SMB-Proxy using autofs through smbd
To separate our insecure smb-v1 enabled network we intend to set up a server that reshares the smb-v1 shares using smb-v2/3.
While trying to set up the server using a combination of smbd and autofs, we are running in a problem with smbd incorrectly listing the files in automounted shares. Setting up a share from the automount root directory will result in empty directory listings (even with ghosting enabled). On the other hand using the share directly, will correctly list the contents (see below). For the sake of simplicity I reduced the automount script to a single share, however in practice we want to dynamically access a lot of different shares (think auto.smb).
It seems like smbd is using some internal caching while listing the contents of a directory.
What are we missing? Are there any configuration parameters or samba-vfs-modules to solve the problem?
System Info
$> uname-srv
Linux 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024

$> cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

$> smbd --version
Version 4.19.5-Ubuntu

$> automount --version
Linux automount version 5.1.9

Directories:
        config dir:     /etc/default
        maps dir:       /etc
        modules dir:    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/autofs

Compile options:
  DISABLE_MOUNT_LOCKING ENABLE_FORCED_SHUTDOWN ENABLE_IGNORE_BUSY_MOUNTS
  WITH_HESIOD WITH_LDAP WITH_SASL LIBXML2_WORKAROUND WITH_LIBTIRPC

Configuration:
/etc/auto.master:
+auto.master
/mnt/shares /etc/auto.shares -t 15 -n 15 browse

/etc/auto.shares
<ip-addr> -fstype=cifs,uid=1000,credentials=/etc/smbproxy-credentials ://<ip-addr>/share

/etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
load printers = No
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
log level = 3
logging = file
max log size = 1000

[shares]
path = /mnt/shares
browseable = yes

#[share]
#path = /mnt/shares/<ip-addr>
#browseable = yes

Steps to reproduce:
Working
$>sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USER,uid=1000 //<server-ip>/share mnt
$>ls mnt
file.txt

Broken
$>sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USER,uid=1000 //<server-ip>/shares mnt
$>ls mnt
<ip-addr>
$>ls mnt/<ip-addr>

Logs:
automount -f -v
Starting automounter version 5.1.9, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.05
reading dir master /etc/auto.master.d
reading files master auto.master
mounted indirect on /mnt/shares with timeout 15, freq 4 seconds
ghosting enabled

In some variations of the configuration automount did actually mount the share triggered by a client (mounted /mnt/shares/<ip-addr>). However listing the directory from a client still results in an empty response. Listing the directory from the server will correctly mount the files. Clients will then also correctly list the files until timeout.
/var/log/samba/log.:
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.463082,  3] lib/util/access.c:372(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from <client-ip> (<client-ip>)
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.463123,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_service.c:584(make_connection_snum)
  make_connection_snum: Connect path is '/tmp' for service [IPC$]
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.463144,  3] source3/smbd/vfs.c:115(vfs_init_default)
  Initialising default vfs hooks
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.463150,  3] source3/smbd/vfs.c:141(vfs_init_custom)
  Initialising custom vfs hooks from [/[Default VFS]/]
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.465122,  3] lib/util/access.c:372(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from <client-ip> (<client-ip>)
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.465145,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_service.c:584(make_connection_snum)
  make_connection_snum: Connect path is '/mnt/shares' for service [shares]
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.465154,  3] source3/smbd/vfs.c:115(vfs_init_default)
  Initialising default vfs hooks
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.465157,  3] source3/smbd/vfs.c:141(vfs_init_custom)
  Initialising custom vfs hooks from [/[Default VFS]/]
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.465216,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_service.c:814(make_connection_snum)
   (ipv4:<client-ip>:60528) signed connect to service shares initially as user AUDUSER (uid=1001, gid=1001) (pid 47117)
  added interface ens35 ip=<server-ip> bcast=<server-broadcast> netmask=255.255.255.0
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.470910,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_trans2.c:2078(smbd_do_qfsinfo)
  smbd_do_qfsinfo: level = 1005
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.472886,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_trans2.c:2078(smbd_do_qfsinfo)
  smbd_do_qfsinfo: level = 1004
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.474503,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_trans2.c:2078(smbd_do_qfsinfo)
  smbd_do_qfsinfo: level = 1001
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.476170,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_trans2.c:2078(smbd_do_qfsinfo)
  smbd_do_qfsinfo: level = 1011
[2024/05/21 10:55:02.488176,  3] source3/smbd/dir.c:799(smbd_dirptr_get_entry)
  smbd_dirptr_get_entry: mask=[*] found . fname=. (.)
[2024/05/21 10:55:02.488217,  3] source3/smbd/dir.c:799(smbd_dirptr_get_entry)
  smbd_dirptr_get_entry: mask=[*] found . fname=.. (..)
[2024/05/21 10:55:02.488242,  3] source3/smbd/dir.c:799(smbd_dirptr_get_entry)
  smbd_dirptr_get_entry: mask=[*] found <ip-addr> fname=<ip-addr> (<ip-addr>)
[2024/05/21 10:55:02.491734,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:4031(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES] || at source3/smbd/smb2_query_directory.c:160
[2024/05/21 10:55:15.681831,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:4031(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND] || at source3/smbd/smb2_create.c:360
[2024/05/21 10:55:15.681875,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:4031(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[5] status[NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND] || at source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3400

/var/logs/samba/log.client-ip
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.449576,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_oplock.c:1408(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.451109,  3] source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:345(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB3_11
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453134,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453160,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453164,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453168,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453177,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453181,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ncalrpc_as_system' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453184,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453187,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453190,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453194,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453197,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453200,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_negotiate' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453205,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.453208,  3] auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:1083(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.456578,  3] auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0xe0080225
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.458487,  3] auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:509(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[USER] domain=[] workstation=[] len1=0 len2=124
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.458514,  3] source3/auth/auth.c:202(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  auth_check_ntlm_password: check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user []\[USER]@[] with the new password interface
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.458518,  3] source3/auth/auth.c:208(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  auth_check_ntlm_password: check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: []\[USER]@[]
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.459103,  3] source3/passdb/lookup_sid.c:1720(get_primary_group_sid)
  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for USER
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.459473,  3] source3/passdb/lookup_sid.c:1720(get_primary_group_sid)
  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for USER
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460135,  3] source3/auth/auth.c:274(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  auth_check_ntlm_password: sam_ignoredomain authentication for user [USER] succeeded
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460171,  3] auth/auth_log.c:858(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user []\[USER] at [Tue, 21 May 2024 10:54:59.460157 UTC] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [] remote host [ipv4:172.17.6.111:60528] became [HREINTF4]\[USER] [S-1-5-21-2771446700-4175686059-33351354-1000]. local host [ipv4:170.56.67.92:445]
  {"timestamp": "2024-05-21T10:54:59.460247+0000", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 3}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "0", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": "ipv4:170.56.67.92:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:172.17.6.111:60528", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "", "clientAccount": "USER", "workstation": "", "becameAccount": "USER", "becameDomain": "HREINTF4", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-2771446700-4175686059-33351354-1000", "mappedAccount": "USER", "mappedDomain": "", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "clientPolicyAccessCheck": null, "serverPolicyAccessCheck": null, "duration": 3726}}
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460280,  2] source3/auth/auth.c:332(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [USER] -> [USER] -> [USER] succeeded
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460286,  3] source3/param/loadparm.c:3997(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460325,  3] source3/param/loadparm.c:559(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460372,  3] source3/param/loadparm.c:2899(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460396,  2] source3/param/loadparm.c:2916(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[shares]"
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460406,  2] source3/param/loadparm.c:2916(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[share]"
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460422,  3] source3/param/loadparm.c:1683(lp_add_ipc)
  adding IPC service
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.460734,  3] source3/auth/token_util.c:688(finalize_local_nt_token)
  Failed to fetch domain sid for WORKGROUP
[2024/05/21 10:54:59.461110,  3] source3/smbd/password.c:84(register_homes_share)
  Adding homes service for user 'USER' using home directory: '/home/USER'

